# Error al convertir html to PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Cuando estoy tratando de convertir mi html a pdf me sale un error en la libreria html2canvas error: [image: error]

Y este es mi JavaScript para renderizar en html2canvas y jsPDF

```js
function btnPDF(){
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var margin = 10;
    var scale = (doc.internal.pageSize.width - margin * 2) / document.body.scrollWidth;
    doc.html(document.body, {
        x: margin,
        y: margin,
        html2canvas: {
            scale: scale, 
        },
        callback: function(doc){
            doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', {filename: 'examen.pdf'});
        }
    });
}
```

Este es mi codigo HTML

```html
<center><div  class="container">
        <center><h1>Formulario</h1></center>
        <form class="form-duplicate" action="" method="post"><div class="formulario-dividido" id="formulario-dividido">
            <div class="inputs">
                <h6>Envio de datos</h6>
                <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Nombre</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Apellido</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Telefono</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Contraseña</span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Buscar</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar Solicitud" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                  </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="btnPDF()" class="btn btn-primary" >Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div></form>
        <div class="duplicates">

        </div>
        <button onclick="addProduct()" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo paciente</button>
    </div></center>
```

Habia probado en otro documento y me funciona correctamente pero lo pruebo en el documento que lo necesito y me sale ese error.

Así estoy llamando el jsPDF y html2canvas también trate de cambiar la versión de ambas librerías y pasa exactamente lo mismo

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el contenido del código HTML que estás tratando de renderizar?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez Claro, acabe de editar y subí mi HTML

Answer (score 1):

Este error ocurre cuando intentas dibujar un borde (dashed o dotted) con versiones inferiores a la 2.4.0 de `jsPDF`.

En la versión que usas de `jsPDF`, **no existe** la declaración de la función `setLineDash` en el `Context2D` del `Canvas` que es posteriormente utilizado por `html2canvas` para renderizar el PDF. Esta información es mencionada [aquí](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/pull/3169) y [aquí](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3136)

La función fue agregada a partir de la [v2.0.4](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/releases/tag/v2.4.0), así que para solucionarlo, utiliza una versión superior (se recomienda usar la más actualizada en la medida de lo posible).

---

Las librerías quedarían así:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Y tu código quedaría así:

```
function btnPDF(){

    // Tomar en cuenta que la manera en que se accede al objeto se utiliza diferente en la versión UMD.
    // También podrías declarar jsPDF en una variable global y utilizarla aquí.
    var doc = new window['jspdf'].jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

    var margin = 10;
    var scale = (doc.internal.pageSize.width - margin * 2) / document.body.scrollWidth;
    doc.html(document.body, {
        x: margin,
        y: margin,
        html2canvas: {
            scale: scale, 
        },
        callback: function(doc){
            doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', {filename: 'examen.pdf'});
        }
    });
}
```

---

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo verificable](https://codepen.io/crodriguez25/pen/PoOyXmV)